# Force square corners on edges with graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have the following `.dot` file.

```
digraph
{
    node [color=Limegreen,fontcolor=Limegreen,shape=oval]
    ilocus [label="iLocus"]
    gilocus [label="giLocus"]
    pilocus [label="piLocus"]
    nilocus [label="niLocus"]
    silocus [label="siLocus"]
    cilocus [label="ciLocus"]
    filocus [label="fiLocus"]
    iilocus [label="iiLocus"]

    node [color=Blue,fontcolor=Blue,shape=diamond]
    containgene [label="Contains gene(s)?"]
    proteincoding [label="Protein coding?"]
    multiplegenes [label="Multiple genes?"]
    geneflank [label="Flanked by genes\non both sides?"]

    ilocus -> containgene
    containgene:e -> geneflank [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:e -> filocus [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:w -> iilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    containgene:w -> gilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    gilocus -> proteincoding
    proteincoding:e -> nilocus [xlabel="No"]
    proteincoding:w -> pilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    pilocus -> multiplegenes
    multiplegenes:e -> silocus [xlabel="No"]
    multiplegenes:w -> cilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
}
```

Rendering with graphviz I get the following.

[image: Graphviz take 1]

Is there any way I can force the edges to have square corners rather than rounded corners? The `splines=ortho` attribute from the documentation seems to be designed for this in principle, but in practice I just get straight lines when I add `graph [splines=ortho]` to my digraph.

[image: Graphviz take 2]

Any way I can get square corners on the edges with graphviz? Something like the following:

```
  ------ Multiple genes? -----
  |                          |
  | N                      Y |
  |                          |
  v                          V
siLocus                   ciLocus
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can start out by using `splines=line`

```
digraph
{
    splines=line
    ...
```

which will give you this graph:

[image: Graph using splines=line]

From there you might need to manually position the nodes, or insert hidden nodes and edges like

```
digraph
{
    splines=line

    node [color=Limegreen,fontcolor=Limegreen,shape=oval]
    ilocus [label="iLocus"]
    gilocus [label="giLocus"]
    pilocus [label="piLocus"]
    nilocus [label="niLocus"]
    silocus [label="siLocus"]
    cilocus [label="ciLocus"]
    filocus [label="fiLocus"]
    iilocus [label="iiLocus"]

    node [color=Blue,fontcolor=Blue,shape=diamond]
    containgene [label="Contains gene(s)?"]
    proteincoding [label="Protein coding?"]
    multiplegenes [label="Multiple genes?"]
    geneflank [label="Flanked by genes\non both sides?"]

    spacer1 [label="xxxx",style=invis]
    {rank=same gilocus spacer1 geneflank}
    gilocus -> spacer1 -> geneflank [style=invis]

    ilocus -> containgene
    containgene:e -> geneflank [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:e -> filocus [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:w -> iilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    containgene:w -> gilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    gilocus -> proteincoding
    proteincoding:e -> nilocus [xlabel="No"]
    proteincoding:w -> pilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    pilocus -> multiplegenes
    multiplegenes:e -> silocus [xlabel="No"]
    multiplegenes:w -> cilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
}
```

which produces

[image]

Alternatively, you can insert spaces in the top labels to make lower nodes line up better:

```
digraph
{
    splines=line

    node [color=Limegreen,fontcolor=Limegreen,shape=oval]
    ilocus [label="iLocus"]
    gilocus [label="giLocus"]
    pilocus [label="piLocus"]
    nilocus [label="niLocus"]
    silocus [label="siLocus"]
    cilocus [label="ciLocus"]
    filocus [label="fiLocus"]
    iilocus [label="iiLocus"]

    node [color=Blue,fontcolor=Blue,shape=diamond]
    containgene [label="    Contains gene(s)?   "]
    proteincoding [label="Protein coding?"]
    multiplegenes [label="Multiple genes?"]
    geneflank [label="Flanked by genes\non both sides?"]

    ilocus -> containgene
    containgene:e -> geneflank [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:e -> filocus [xlabel="No"]
    geneflank:w -> iilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    containgene:w -> gilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    gilocus -> proteincoding
    proteincoding:e -> nilocus [xlabel="No"]
    proteincoding:w -> pilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
    pilocus -> multiplegenes
    multiplegenes:e -> silocus [xlabel="No"]
    multiplegenes:w -> cilocus [xlabel="Yes"]
}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Definitely helpful, but frustrating that I can't get a 90° angle on, for example, the "No" edge between "Contains gene(s)?" and "Flanked by genes on both sides?".

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `splines=false` ([link to GraphvizFiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/?1453796919435#digraph%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20splines%3Dfalse%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bcolor%3DLimegreen%2Cfontcolor%3DLimegreen%2Cshape%3Doval%5D%0A%20%20%20%20ilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22iLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20gilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22giLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20pilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22piLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20nilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22niLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20silocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22siLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20cilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22ciLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20filocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22fiLocus%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20iilocus%20%5Blabel%3D%22iiLocus%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bcolor%3DBlue%2Cfontcolor%3DBlue%2Cshape%3Ddiamond%5D%0A%20%20%20%20containgene%20%5Blabel%3D%22Contains%20gene(s)%3F%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20proteincoding%20%5Blabel%3D%22Protein%20coding%3F%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20multiplegenes%20%5Blabel%3D%22Multiple%20genes%3F%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20geneflank%20%5Blabel%3D%22Flanked%20by%20genes%5Cnon%20both%20sides%3F%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20ilocus%20-%3E%20containgene%0A%20%20%20%20containgene%3Ae%20-%3E%20geneflank%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22No%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20geneflank%3Ae%20-%3E%20filocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22No%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20geneflank%3Aw%20-%3E%20iilocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22Yes%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20containgene%3Aw%20-%3E%20gilocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22Yes%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20gilocus%20-%3E%20proteincoding%0A%20%20%20%20proteincoding%3Ae%20-%3E%20nilocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22No%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20proteincoding%3Aw%20-%3E%20pilocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22Yes%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20pilocus%20-%3E%20multiplegenes%0A%20%20%20%20multiplegenes%3Ae%20-%3E%20silocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22No%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20multiplegenes%3Aw%20-%3E%20cilocus%20%5Bxlabel%3D%22Yes%22%5D%0A%7D)).

Comment: Maybe my explanation wasn't clear. I've updated to show precisely what I mean by "square corners".

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. Unfortunately ortho rarely does what one wants it to do...